# How to put external URL hyperlink in Google Map HTML infoWindow?

Tags: google-maps, url

I have generated XML in format:

```
  <marker lat="41.932797" lng="21.483765" url="https://myhostname.com/webtop/AELView/?textdirection=LTR&guiorientation=LTR&filtername=Example_Unassigned&filtertype=system"  severity="0"  />
  <marker lat="41.532797" lng="21.183767" url="https://myhostname.com/webtop/AELView/?textdirection=LTR&guiorientation=LTR&filtername=Example_Unassigned&filtertype=device" severity="1"  />
```

I want to put external URL address in infoWindow on marker when I click it.
But if I put this in XML my map does not show any markers.
If I cut this URL address on example just to the https://myhostname.com/webtop/AELView infoWindow shows this but as a normal text not URL. ***How to enable so when click on marker I can click and go to the external URL address?***
My only HTML file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body onunload="GUnload()">

    <table border=1>
      <tr>
        <td>
           <div id="map" style="width: 1550px; height: 1450px"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {

      var gmarkers = [];


      function createMarker(point,name,alarm) {
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
   // **this is where I wan to call URL**

          marker.openInfoWindowHtml(alarm);
        });

        return marker;
      }



      function myclick(i) {
        GEvent.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
      }


      var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
      map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
      map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
      map.setCenter(new GLatLng( 41.932797,21.483765), 10);



      GDownloadUrl("alarms.xml", function(doc) {
        var xmlDoc = GXml.parse(doc);
        var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          // obtain the attribues of each marker
          var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
          var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
          var point = new GLatLng(lat,lng);
          var alarm = markers[i].getAttribute("alarm");
          var label = markers[i].getAttribute("label");
          // create the marker
          var marker = createMarker(point,label,alarm);
          map.addOverlay(marker);
        }

      });
    }




    //]]>
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you XML is invalid , so it cannot be parsed.
The & inside the url-attributes have to be encoded as `&amp;`

Apart from that: there are no attributes "alarm" inside the XML.

This currently would show a Link inside the infoWindow(when the XML is fixed):
Now:

```
var alarm = markers[i].getAttribute("alarm");
```

Then:

```
var alarm = document.createElement('a');
    alarm.setAttribute('href',markers[i].getAttribute('url'));
    alarm.appendChild(document.createTextNode('click here'));
```